# Can someone find out what phone was used to send an email

Tags: account-security, gmail, smartphone, tracking

Can someone find out exactly what phone/phone number an email was sent from? Say Doug used sallys phone to sign in and check his gmail account but never signed out then sally opened his gmail and sent an email using his account.. is there a way to find out that that email did infact come from sallys phone and not Doug's?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IP address by looking at the RAW email. gmail has this option when you are in the mail you want to check, go into the little down arrow that says more and choose "show original" the IP information is in there. Take time to read it, as there is more than 1 IP involved in getting your mail there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gmail's [Account Activity](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) pane. If you know where each device should've been and at what time you can use a correlation between the sign in times and the email send times, assuming they signed into the web client. This is far easier if the two devices were on cellular data and are from two different carriers because different ISPs/carriers have different blocks that are known to be assigned to them.